# Is it bad practice to set href="../" for link to Home page?

Tags: html, url, server, hyperlink, anchor

Quite simply, I have a webpage with a navbar menu.  I would normally use href="./index.php" for the "Home" link, but I am wondering if there is a good reason not to switch it to href="../" to achieve the same (only without index.php appearing in the URL)??

Answer (score 1):

```
 ./ - current folder
../ - parent folder of current folder
  / - root of server
```

Suppose your current page is located at root of server (`/`)

Then You can use all of above to go to index.php because you will redirect always to index page.

It is not bad practice, you just saved your important time for typing 9 letters.